# ScrollView + NavigationBar (glimmer effect)

Tags: swiftui

Could you please tell me why this effect occurs (navigationBar flickers when ScrollView is scrolling) and how to get rid of it?

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    let color = Color(red: 38/255, green: 46/255, blue: 48/255)
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            color.ignoresSafeArea()
            ScrollView {
                Text("Test")
            }
            .toolbarBackground(color, for: .navigationBar)
            .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.interactively)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: gif]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce the problem using the code you provided when running on an iPhone 14 simulator with iOS 17.

However, I suspect that it is being caused by the white background from a parent view.

You could try setting a darker background on the parent view and/or setting `.dark` as the preferred color scheme:

```swift
ParentView()
    .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
```

Comment: That's it =) thanks, Benzy!